# To select an item with a button/ I need help somebody.. using visual basic

Tags: vb.net

First of all, what I'm using is Visual Basic.

I have a list box with items.

like

item1
item2
item3
item4
item5

I want to change the selected item using the up-down button.
If 1 is selected and the down button is pressed, then 2 is selected just below.

I searched on Google for hours, but I couldn't find out. Can I get codes?

Comment: If you searched for hours and couldn't find anything then you must have chosen your search keywords very poorly. All you need to do is increment or decrement the `SelectedIndex`. Couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Like jmcilhinney suggested , use SelectedIndex.

A small example found in 10 seconds .

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim arry() As String = {"item1", "item2", "item3"}
    'bind the array to the listbox 
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(arry)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'show the index of selected item 
    MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

Or show the item

```
 MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
```